# Как открыть приложение на макос в определенном окне?

Tags: bash, excel, macos, mac

У меня есть скрипт, который открывает ексель каждые 3 часа, не спрашивайте зачем. Скрипт bash, мне надо чтобы открывалось либо как то в фоновом режиме, либо хотя бы в определенное окно, например, я работаю в первом окне, есть еще активных 3 окна и чтоб программа открывалась во втором. Как это возможно реализовать? 
Надо под MacOs

Comment: видимо, помимо posix-совместимой оболчки, придётся вам изучить ещё и [applescript](http://blog.viktorkelemen.com/2011/07/resize-and-position-windows-with.html).

Comment: нашел решение, можно внизу в доке, предварительно свернув на нужный рабочий стол, назначить  "Этот рабочий стол"

Comment: вот как еще бы сделать чтоб он мое окно рабочее не переводил  в окно где открывается программа) если кто знает отпишите, пожалуйста